# Probability: MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution broken with more than five categories?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, system-performance

### 2016-04-09: This bug is indeed fixed (thank you, Stefan R.!) in 10.4. It may have been fixed in 10.3 or 10.3.1, but I haven't tried these versions.

```
dist=MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[5,ConstantArray[2,10]];
prob=Probability[a==1,Distributed[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j},dist]]
```

We stuff an urn with coloured balls, ten colours, two balls of each colour, for a total of twenty. We draw five balls without replacing them; the list `{a,…,j}` then (loosely speaking) represents what we just have drawn. The probability of picking exactly one ball of colour "a" `P(a==1)` then comes out to 15/38, easily verified and computed in a snap by Mathematica.

What about `P(a==1&&b==1)`, the probability of getting exactly one "a" and one "b" ball each? You can probably model this in your head, do the calculation with pencil and paper – and finish long before Mathematica 10.2, which hasn't finished yet in the time it took me to type all this.

Or just checking for `P(a==1&&b<0)`? Neat, the answer is instantaneous and correct (p==0). And since the number of balls of colour "b" must obviously be at least 0, let's try this, too:

```
dist=MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[5,{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}];
prob=Probability[a==1&&b>=0,Distributed[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j},dist]]
```

`P(a==1||b>=0)`? No luck. `P(a==b)`? Perhaps next week. `P(a!=b)`? Nope.

Apparently, the cutoff is at five dimensions, that is, when the length of the `list` that is passed to `MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[n,list]` becomes greater than five. Up to five, everything works as expected.

My question is, I fear, obvious and not very specific: What am I doing wrong? Or must I keep recalling my high-school maths and calculate my probabilities on an abacus?

Comment: Not doing anything "wrong", this is an area of weakness in an otherwise quite nice set of facilities: sometimes you just have to use manual intervention to transform the problem...

Comment: @ciao Thanks, that is a relief. Maybe in MMA 11 …

Comment: See my CW answer.... might be of use.

Comment: Thanks for this question! We've looked into it and found that we can substantially speed up this computation. The next version of _Mathematica_ will be able to find this probability  in less than a second.

Comment: @StefanR Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of my few gripes re: an otherwise quite nice probability functionality. Sometimes, performance is inexplicably poor.

Usually, trivial manual transformation/intervention can get the results desired speedily, e.g., your example cases:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

dist = MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[5, ConstantArray[2, 10]];

PDF[dist, 
  Cases[Join @@ 
    Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[5, {10}, Range[0, 5]], 
        {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_} /; a == 1]] // Tr

PDF[dist, 
  Cases[Join @@ 
    Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[5, {10}, Range[0, 5]], 
    {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_} /; a == 1 && b >= 0]] // Tr

PDF[dist, 
  Cases[Join @@ 
    Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[5, {10}, Range[0, 5]], 
       {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_} /; a == b]] // Tr

PDF[dist, 
  Cases[Join @@ 
    Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[5, {10}, Range[0, 5]], 
    {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_} /; a != b]] // Tr
```

All return quickly.

When only certain categories are involved, further transformation will speed things hugely:

```
dist = MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[5, Append[ConstantArray[2, 2], 16]];

PDF[dist, 
  Cases[Join @@ 
    Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[5, {3}, Range[0, 5]], {a_, b_, c_} /; a != b]] // Tr
```

Obviously, for cases with equal categories, further speed can be had by dispensing with permutations and applying appropriate factor to each result for number of permutations.

Lastly, for ranged queries, see [How to get probabilities for multinomial & hypergeometric distribution ranges more quickly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77386/11467), a little sorcery I cooked up...

Comment: Thank you! I had already found your article on ranges with multivariate hypergeometric distributions and was prepared to solve my problem "by hand", a task which you were so kind as to anticipate, but ranges were not quite what I needed. Also, I wanted to be sure that I was dealing with an idiosyncrasy in MMA and not just with my own daftness …

Answer (score 7):

Although @ciao's solution gets you to the answer, I would like to offer perhaps another angle at it.

Given a tuple $\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ that follows a multivariate hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N$, $\{M_1, \ldots, M_n\}$, the tuple $\{X_1, X_2, \sum_{k=3}^n X_k \}$ also follows a multivariate hypergeometric with parameters $N$ and $\{M_1, M_2, \sum_{k=3}^n M_k\}$.

Hence the problem can be reformulated with fewer variables, which leads to a faster solution:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Probability[a == 1 && b >= 0, 
  Distributed[{a, b, c}, 
   MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[
    5, {2, 2, Plus[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}]]]]

(* Out[29]= {0.0504801, 15/38} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 Probability[a == b, 
  Distributed[{a, b, c}, 
   MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[
    5, {2, 2, Plus[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}]]]]

(* Out[30]= {0.0075801, 138/323} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 Probability[a > b, 
  Distributed[{a, b, c}, 
   MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[
    5, {2, 2, Plus[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}]]]]

(* Out[32]= {0.00749303, 185/646} *)
```

Comment: This is the second example in my answer....

Comment: The transformation, which @ciao also hinted at, is elegant and perfectly correct. Regrettably, it does not cover my original case; only looking at two out of ten categories was just a simple case that still demonstrated the sub-optimal behaviour of Mathematica. For my, admittedly rather odd, case, I think ciao's original answer is currently the best option I have. But I am grateful for making explicit and reminding me of the possibility of collapsing unneeded categories!